# pyspark using sklearn.DBSCAN getting error after submit the spark job locally

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I use sklearn.DBSCAN in my pyspark job. See the code snippet below. I also zipped all the dependency modules in deps.zip file which is added to the SparkContext.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np
#import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql import Row

def dbscan_latlng(lat_lngs,mim_distance_km,min_points=10):

coords = np.asmatrix(lat_lngs)
kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
epsilon = mim_distance_km/ kms_per_radian
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=min_points, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coords))
cluster_labels = db.labels_
num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))
clusters = pd.Series([coords[cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
maxClusters = clusters.map(len).max()
if (maxClusters > 3):
  dfClusters = clusters.to_frame('coords')
  dfClusters['length'] = dfClusters.apply(lambda x: len(x['coords']), axis=1)
  custCluster = dfClusters[dfClusters['length']==maxClusters].reset_index()
  return custCluster['coords'][0].tolist()

sc = SparkContext()
sc.addPyFile('/content/airflow/dags/deps.zip')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

However, after I submit the job via spark-submit -master local[4] FindOutliers.py, I get the following python error saying sklearn/__check_build is not a directory. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/root/.virtualenvs/jacob/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 166, in main
>       func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)   File
>   "/root/.virtualenvs/jacob/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 55, in read_command
>       command = serializer._read_with_length(file)   File "/root/.virtualenvs/jacob/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 169, in _read_with_length
>       return self.loads(obj)   File "/root/.virtualenvs/jacob/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 454, in loads
>       return pickle.loads(obj)   File "/tmp/pip-build-0qnWWw/scikit-learn/sklearn/**init**.py", line 133, in
>      File
>   "/tmp/pip-build-0qnWWw/scikit-learn/sklearn/**check_build/__init**.py",
>   line 46, in    File
>   "/tmp/pip-build-0qnWWw/scikit-learn/sklearn/**check_build/__init**.py",
>   line 26, in raise_build_error OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:
>   '/tmp/spark-beb8777f-b7d5-40be-a72b-c16e10264a50/userFiles-3762d9c0-6674-467a-949b-33968420bae1/deps.zip/sklearn/__check_build'

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
import pyspark as ps

sc = ps.SparkContext()
sc.addPyFile('/content/airflow/dags/deps.zip')
sqlContext = ps.SQLContext
```

Comment: Please add some explenation as to why this piece of code answers the question.

Comment: I`m new in python, but i`m tested project with pyspark. I tested locally and it worked. https://github.com/bwoneill/pypardis/blob/master/dbscan.py see line 184